# clearInterval not working after 6 time setInterval

Tags: javascript, counter, setinterval, clearinterval

I want to change an image 6 times to create the illusion of a dice changing the number of dots (a simple animation). But the images don't stop after the 6 time. I think the clearInterval is not working! don't know why

```
   var d = [  "images/dado1.svg",
              "images/dado2.svg",
              "images/dado3.svg",
              "images/dado4.svg",
              "images/dado5.svg",
              "images/dado6.svg",
              ];

window.onload = function (){
                dado.onclick = move;
            }

   function move() {

                 var md = setInterval(mudaDado,500);

                }


    function mudaDado(){

      dado.setAttribute("src",d[time]);

      time++;

      if(time===6){
      clearInterval(md);

      }

    }
```

Comment: `md` is not defined in the scope where you call `clearInterval(md);`. Define `md` in common scope of the `setInterval` and `clearInterval` calls.

Comment: You have defined `md` inside a function, so it is a local variable. In next stage you are trying to `clearInterval` for `md` which is referring to no where. added: @FelixKling has answered first.

Comment: Thanksssss! It works. I didn't notice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign md to global variable:-

```
var md;
 var d = [  "images/dado1.svg",
              "images/dado2.svg",
              "images/dado3.svg",
              "images/dado4.svg",
              "images/dado5.svg",
              "images/dado6.svg",
              ];

window.onload = function (){
                dado.onclick = move;
            }

   function move() {

                 md = setInterval(mudaDado,500);

                }


    function mudaDado(){

      dado.setAttribute("src",d[time]);

      time++;

      if(time===6){
      clearInterval(md);

      }

    }
```